# promise.then() and promise.catch() not working in node program

Tags: javascript, node.js, opencv, events, es6-promise

I am trying to display a live stream which is read by opencv4nodejs and processed by face-recognition module. Here problem is, promise.then() is not working. not even catch() on the corresponding condition.(i am new at node and promises.)
expected workflow:

> read frame from webcam(by cv.read) -> save to buffer(by cv.imwrite) ->
>   read frame from buffer(by fr.loadImage) -> process(by detector.locateFaces) -> display -> repeat process.

```
const fr = require('face-recognition');
const cv = require('opencv4nodejs');
const events = require('events');

const detector = fr.FaceDetector()
const cap = new cv.VideoCapture(0);
const win = new fr.ImageWindow()
const eventEmitter = new events.EventEmitter();

function process(){
    console.log('process');
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        console.log('promise');
        var frame = cap.read();
        cv.imwrite(`${__dirname}/buffer/img.jpg`, frame);
        if(frame != null)
            resolve('resolve');
        else
            reject('Problem While reading');
    });
}
eventEmitter.on('read',function(string){
    console.log('event call');
    var promise = process();
    promise.then(function(string){
        console.log(string);
        const image = fr.loadImage(`${__dirname}/buffer/img.jpg`);
        const faceRectangles = detector.locateFaces(image);
        win.setImage(image);
        fr.hitEnterToContinue();
    }).catch(function(err){
        console.log(err);
    });
});
while(true){
    console.log('emit');
    eventEmitter.emit('read','abcd');
}
/*****expected output should be*****
emit
event call
process
promise
resolve
/*****getting output*****
emit
event call
process
promise
*/
```

Comment: Can you console.log the promise variable before trying to use the .then method? And send the result here.

Comment: `emit
    event call
    process
    promise
    Promise { 'resolve' }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const fr = require('face-recognition');
const cv = require('opencv4nodejs');
const events = require('events');

const detector = fr.FaceDetector()
const cap = new cv.VideoCapture(0);
const win = new fr.ImageWindow()
const eventEmitter = new events.EventEmitter();

function process(){
    console.log('process');
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        console.log('promise');
        var frame = cap.read();
        cv.imwrite(`${__dirname}/buffer/img.jpg`, frame);
        if(frame != null)
            resolve('resolve');
        else
            reject('Problem While reading');
    });
}
eventEmitter.on('read',function(string){
    console.log('event call');
    var promise = process();
    console.log(promise);
    promise.then(function(string){
        console.log(string);
        const image = fr.loadImage(`${__dirname}/buffer/img.jpg`);
        const faceRectangles = detector.locateFaces(image);
        console.log(faceRectangles);
        win.setImage(image);
        // fr.hitEnterToContinue();
        eventEmitter.emit('read','abcd');
    }).catch(function(err){
        console.log(err);
    });
});
eventEmitter.emit('read','abcd');
```

changes:
1)remove while loop from `eventEmitter.emit('read','abcd');`
2)recursively emit event in `promise.then()`
I observed that while emitting event continuously promise.then() not working so i emit event in promise.then() so now its working nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using eventEmitter your code should look like this:

```
const fr = require('face-recognition');
const cv = require('opencv4nodejs');
const events = require('events');
const Promise = require('bluebird');

const detector = fr.FaceDetector()
const cap = new cv.VideoCapture(0);
const win = new fr.ImageWindow()
const eventEmitter = new events.EventEmitter();

function process(){
    console.log('process');
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {
        console.log('promise');
        var frame = cap.read();
        cv.imwrite(`${__dirname}/buffer/img.jpg`, frame);
        if(frame != null)
            resolve();
        else
            reject('Problem While reading');
    });
}
eventEmitter.on('read',function(string){
    console.log('event call');
    var promise = process();
    promise.then(function(string){
        console.log(string);
        const image = fr.loadImage(`${__dirname}/buffer/img.jpg`);
        const faceRectangles = detector.locateFaces(image);
        win.setImage(image);
        fr.hitEnterToContinue();
    }).catch(function(err){
        console.log(err);
    });
});
while(true){
    console.log('emit');
    eventEmitter.emit('read','abcd');
}
```

Comment: if you know another way than, please tell me..!